# Keep getting unique key Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, arrays, components, key, mobx

I'm figuring out what in this code imples i dont have the keys for the pushed array items:

```
    import { Accordion, AccordionSummary } from '@material-ui/core'
    import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
    import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore'
    import Skeleton from '@material-ui/lab/Skeleton'
    import { observer } from 'mobx-react'
    import React from 'react'
    import { PrintEvent } from '../../stores/BoxStore'
    import { useStores } from '../../stores/RootStore'
    import { toRGBA } from '../../utilities/ColorHelpers'
    import { StateCard } from '../StateCard'
    import { StatusPanel } from '../StatusPanel'
    import { AccordionItem } from './AccordionItem'
    
    export const EventAccordionSidebar: React.FC = observer((printEvent: PrintEvent) => {
    
       const { box, ui } = useStores()
    
        const { id } = printEvent
    
        const classes = useStyles()
        let eventList: any[] = []
    
    box.descEvents.forEach((printEvent: PrintEvent, id: number) => {
    
    
            if (!printEvent) {
                return null
            }
    
     eventList.push(
                <React.Fragment>
                    <AccordionItem
                        key={id}
                        printEventDisplay={printEventDisplay}
                        printEvent={printEvent}
                        eventName={eventName}
                        eventSource={eventSource ? eventSource : null}
                        eventID={eventID}
                        eventLineNumber={eventLineNumber}
                        printEventValue={printEventValue}
                        eventKey={id} />
                </React.Fragment>
            )
       })
    
     return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className={classes.eventsContainer}>
                    <StatusPanel />
                    <div className={classes.events}>
                        {/* {eventList.map(event => <li key={id}>{event}</li>)} */}
                        {eventList}
                    </div>
                    <StateCard />
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    })
})

    
    export default EventAccordionSidebar
```

what am i missing here? do i put the key in one place or everywhere?
strack tracing its only on this component.

I am using MobX for observing state and decorations.

Please help.

[image: unique key warning chrome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe the answer lies here in the empty array :

```
let eventList: any[] = []
```

the eventList cannot have no keys in the first instance, its going to look for the keys if the items are loaded.

however, pushing keys in the map in the return solved this..

```
<div className={classes.eventsContainer} key={id}>
        <StatusPanel />
        <div className={classes.events} key={id}>
            {eventList.map((eventItem, key) =>

                <div key={key}>
                    {eventItem}
                </div>)}
            {/* <ul>{eventList}</ul> */}
        </div>
        <StateCard />
    </div>
```

Comment: You are using keys incorrectly, you don't need to set them outside of any loops/maps and etc. My answer already gave you correct explanation that you set the key on the wrong element (not top one). `eventList.map` in your original example was commented out completely, even though it used same id for all elements.

Answer (score 0):

`key` should be added to the top level component, you have `<React.Fragment>` as a top level, which wraps `AccordionItem`, so just add `key` to the Fragment instead. Although your Fragment is kind of useless there, you don't need it at all, I think it can be removed.

Comment: i understand this , but nnetheless the errors keep reappearing.

Comment: @FaridGuzman then you have more cases where you made the same mistake, just check all of them carefully